# How to apply changes to an Android Cordova App Java source file using PhoneGap CLI?

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to insert some native functionality into my Android app built with PhoneGap/Cordova (v4.2). Specifically, I want to override the `onWindowFocusChanged()` of the `CordovaActivity` class in my app, and I don't think I can do this through a plugin. (*I'm building a kiosk application and I want to collapse the status bar as soon as it is opened. The code works in another app (which is native) and I'm trying to do the same here*)

I've already edited the `CordovaApp.java` file located in `platform/android/src/[package-name-inverse-URI]`, rebuilt the project using the CLI command `phonegap build android` to generate an APK, but unfortunately, I was not successful.

Oddly enough, even when I purposely type erroneous/invalid java code into that file and rebuild, no error messages are displayed, which led me to believe that this file is not compiled at all on the build process.

Is there any way that I could edit the main activity file and compile it into the APK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When erroneous code is added to the main activity java file, cordova actually tries to compile it, obviously fails and silently exits. To phonegap, which runs over Cordova in the NPM module, the build process is successful.

To actually see the error output of the Java compiler, you'd need to add the verbose/debug flag, calling:

```
phonegap build android -d
```

With that output, I've managed to see what was wrong with the code and fix it.